# Reversing checksum calculation of embedded communication

Tags: decryption, serial-communication, packet, crc

I need to find relations last byte with others. Tried these solutions, but it didn't work.

My tries:
* When I write all datas as binary, 1's count not equal but last byte same for some datas.
* When I sum all datas and divide by 3 or 4, it equals to last byte, but for future, maybe it's not stable.

Bunch of data:

```
FC 41 01 30 10 01 21 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5B
FC 41 01 30 10 01 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5C

FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4A
FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4B
FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4E
FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52
FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 53
FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 58
FC 41 01 30 10 01 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 59

FC 41 01 30 10 01 22 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5A
FC 41 01 30 10 01 22 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 58
FC 41 01 30 10 01 22 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54
FC 41 01 30 10 01 22 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 59

FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 0D 00 00 AF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9E
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 0F 00 00 B2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 99
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 10 00 00 B4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 96
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 11 00 00 B6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 93
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 11 00 00 B7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 92
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 12 00 00 B9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8F
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 12 00 00 B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 13 00 00 BA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8D
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 14 00 00 BD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 89
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 15 00 00 BE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 87
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 16 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84
FC 62 01 30 10 03 00 00 1C 00 00 D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6E
```

Thank you,

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the first constant byte (`FC`), all the other bytes add up to `00`, ignoring overflow.

In other words, to calculate the last byte, start with `00`, subtract all bytes except the first `FC` (and the last one, obviously). Ignore underflow. The result is the last byte. Or, if that's easier in your programming language, start with `2000` (8192 decimal), subtract all bytes, and `AND` the result with `FF`.

Comment: if your choice of language is powershell you can use this>cat checksum.ps1
$c=(gc .\checksumthis.txt);$s="";0..($c.length-1)|%{$t=0;$l=-split $c[$_];
$l[1..($l.Length-2)]|%{$t+=[convert]::ToSByte($_,16)};$s+="{0:X} "-f(256-$t)}
$s

>powershell -nologo -f .\checksum.ps1
5B 5C 4A 4B 4E 52 53 58 59 5A 58 54 59 9E 99 96 93 92 8F 90 8D 89 87 84 6E

Comment: how did you find this solution? Could you please explain?

Comment: @mcan: Looking at the sequences where only one byte changes, i noticed every payload change by some amount corresponds with a checksum change by the negative amount. (`01-5B`, `00-5C` and `0F-4A`, `0E-4B`, `0B-4E`...) This made me think "constant sum". Then i summed up some of the rows using my trusty hex calculator, and got `FC` (plus some overflow) in every case. That was it.